# Cohomology of punctured euclidean spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm running into a problem with a proof in *From Calculus to Cohomology* but I suspect I'm seeing not seeing something extremely simple. In Proposition 6.11, they prove that $H^{p+1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-A) \cong H^p(\mathbb{R}^n-A)$ and they begin by defining open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$:
$$U_1=\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty)  \cup (\mathbb{R}^n-A) \times (-1,\infty)$$
$$U_2=\mathbb{R}^n \times (-\infty,0) \cup (\mathbb{R}^n-A) \times (-\infty,1)$$
They then claim that $U_1 \cup U_2 = \mathbb{R}^{n+1} -A$, and $U_1 \cap U_2 = (\mathbb{R}^n-A) \times (-1,1)$.

I'm having trouble seeing why $U_1 \cup U_2$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-A$. For example why isn't $U_1$ simply equal to $\mathbb{R}^n \times (-1,\infty)$, and similarly why isn't $U_1 \cup U_2$ simply $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$? An important part of the proof relies on the fact that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are contractible; is this "obvious" in the sense that I should be able to see it once I understand what $U_1$ and $U_2$ are?

Sorry if this is a very simple question. It's frustrating to me that I can't understand the simplest part of the proof! (The following parts, involving homotopy invariance and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence make sense to me if I take the above as given.)

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention. $A$ is an arbitrary closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (not $\mathbb{R}^n$, it seems) and $A \ne \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What is $A$ ${}{}$?

Comment: @AndresMejia I'm sure that $A$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^n=\Bbb R^n\times\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U_1$ isn't $\Bbb R^n\times(-1,\infty)$; it does not contain, say $(-1/2,a)$ for $a\in A$.

$U_1$ deformation retracts to $\Bbb R^n\times\{1\}$ along "vertical lines",
and $\Bbb R^n\times\{1\}$ surely is clearly contractible.

Comment: I see! Thanks for clearing that up for me. I guess my dumb mistake was "distributing" the union over the product.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 6 years since this question was asked, but I stumbled across this problem as well and was equally confused. I figured it was worth including how I approached this problem for future readers. First consider $\textbf{Example 5.4}$ that calculates the de Rham cohomology group of the punctured plane $H^p( \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0,0 \})$. In the example, $U_1$ and $U_2$ are defined as
\begin{align*}
    U_1 &= \left\{ (x,y) \mid x<0 \text{ when } y=0 \right\} \\
    U_2 &= \left\{ (x,y) \mid x > 0 \text{ when } y=0 \right\}
\end{align*}
which can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
    U_1 &= \left( -\infty, 0 \right) \times \mathbb{R} \, \cup \, \left[ 0, \infty \right) \times \left( \mathbb{R}-\{0\} \right) \\
    U_2 &= \left( -\infty, 0 \right] \times \left( \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \right) \, \cup \, \left(0, \infty \right) \times \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
In the case of the example, $U_1 \cup U_2 = \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0,0\}$. For $\textbf{Proposition 6.11}$, we aim to do something similar and find sets $U_1, U_2$ such that $U_1 \cup U_2 = \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0,A \}$ where $A$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A \neq \mathbb{R}^n$. I think the book incorrectly states that A is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, since later sections imply A is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore, generalizing $\textbf{Example 5.4}$ let
\begin{align*}
    U_1 &= \left( -\infty, 0 \right) \times \mathbb{R}^n \, \cup \, \left[ 0, \infty \right) \times \left( \mathbb{R}^n-A \right) \\
    U_2 &= \left( -\infty, 0 \right] \times \left( \mathbb{R}^n - A \right) \, \cup \, \left(0, \infty \right) \times \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}
The union and intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2$ are
\begin{align*}
    U_1 \cup U_2 &= \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0, A\} \\
    U_1 \cap U_2 &= \mathbb{R} \times \left( \mathbb{R}^n - A \right)
\end{align*}
By plugging in $n=1$ and $A=0$, we obtain \begin{align*}
    U_1 \cup U_2 &= \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0,0\} \\
    U_1 \cap U_2 &= \mathbb{R} \times \left( \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \right) = \mathbb{R}^+ \sqcup \mathbb{R}^- 
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{R}^{\pm}$ represents the upper and lower half-planes, respectively.
This is exactly what was found in $\textbf{Example 5.4}$. For the rest of the answer I will denote the coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as $\{r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_{n+1}\}$. For all points with $r_1 \geq 0$, we can define the line segment
\begin{equation*}
    F(x,t) = t\left(-1, r_2, \ldots, r_{n+1} \right) + (1-t)\left(r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_{n+1} \right)
\end{equation*}
to a point with $r_1 \le 0$. This incidentally defines a homotopy between $id_{U_1}$ to a function $\phi(x)$ which changes the $r_1$ coordinate to $-1$. Following from the book, we get homotopies from $id_{U_1}$ to $\phi$, and from $\phi$ to a constant map. Therefore, $U_1$, and similarly $U_2$, are contractible. Finally, the rest of the proof follows like the book, and we get
\begin{align*}
    H^{p+1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0,A \}) &\cong H^p(\mathbb{R}^n - A) \quad \text{ for $p \geq 1$} \\
    H^1(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0,A \}) &\cong H^0(\mathbb{R}^n - A)/\mathbb{R} \cdot 1 \\
    H^0(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0,A \}) &\cong \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

I have also created two images. The first shows a $U_1$ as defined in $\textbf{Example 5.4}$ [(5.4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4OtP.png). The second shows an example of a generalization in $3D$ with a the line segment connecting a point $x$ with $r_1 \geq 0$ to a point $\phi(x)$ with $r_1 \le 0$ [(3D Example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIk8G.png). I hope this helps!